# How can i remove and edit comment item

Tags: comments, forms

how to remove or edit comment item like `fieldset-wrapper`.
just i want the form-type-select show and or edit description in `fieldset` wrapper.
tnx for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to duplicate one of the files with extension .tpl.php in modules/comment directory and place the dup' in your theme. Then clear cache and edit the file you dup'd and placed in your theme.

The File you want is /modules/comment/comment.tpl.php

Comment: please show me complete name of files

Comment: I've added the file you want to the answer.

Comment: tnx  SDMulroy problem is solved